# Python 2.4.3 Multi threading change number of concurrency/threads and finding current concurrency

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, centos, python-multithreading

I was learning multithreading in python and wrote this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time
arg = ["this is one", "this is two", "this is three", "this is four", "this is five"]

def filestat(stat):
    print stat
    print threading.currentThread()
    time.sleep(5)
    print stat,threading.currentThread(),"after sleep"

thread = [threading.Thread(target=filestat, args=(arg[x],)) for x in range(len(arg)) ]
for i in thread:
    i.start()
```

I ran this script, and could see that all the elements in the list are printed simultaneously despite the sleep(5). What is the current level of concurrency in this script? Does it depend on the number of elements in the list? Is there a way I can increase/decrease the concurrency of executing the threads?

Comment: You created 5 different threads and started them all at the same time, so of course you'll get the results all at the same time. `i.start()` isn't going to wait for the thread to finish, it's going to start the current thread, and move to the next iteration - meanwhile each started thread is running on its own in the background.

Comment: @Monkey Thank you, so if I want to limit the concurrency to 2, how would I do that?